# How can I get an input file first click to pop up the keyboard on iphone?

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, input-field, choices.js

I have implemented a search bar using the choices.js package, but when the user clicks on the input field, the keyboard does not pop up, which is not very user friendly and very confusing. I have tried everything from focus on click, to click on tap to whatever you can imagine, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to make a click on an input text field pop up the keyboard on iphone specifically?

I have tried any javascript tricks I could think of, including focus() and click() and tap() and stopPropagation(), and ...

Comment: Could the option `searchEnabled=true` help you?